# Problems with Quotes in python twitter streamer

Tags: python, mysql, twitter

```
user = "'" + "@%s" % data['user']['screen_name'] + "'"
coordinates = "'" + ",".join(str(e)for e in data['coordinates']['coordinates']) + "'"
tweet = "'" + data['text'].encode("ascii", "ignore") + "'"
query = "INSERT INTO tweets (location, tweet, author) values (" + coordinates + "," + tweet + "," + user + ")"
```

I have having issues with tweets are are passed in that have an apostrophe (') or random quote marks which breaks the insert query. Any advice would be appreciated as I would like to reduce errors from tweets inserting. Thanks

Sample error message:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Stadium https://t.co/uJ2U2tcXlr','@Pucker21')' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why *you should not manually construct the query via string interpolation*.

Instead, let the database driver handle it:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO
        tweets 
        (location, tweet, author) 
    VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s)
"""
cursor.execute(query, (coordinates, tweet, user))
```

Here we are creating a *parameterized query*, the `%s` are placeholders for the database driver to fill. The MySQL driver would handle the proper quoting, escaping and making the query *safe from SQL injections*.

Comment: Ah I see. I will edit my mysql_connector class to allow input of these three variables like this then. Thanks

Comment: another question. Now my coordinates are being wrapped by quotes. Any way to prevent this? They should be passed as 1.1111,1.1111 but instead is being passed as '1.1111,1.1111'

Comment: @logepoge1 that's because they are of a string type now. Post the create table query for the `tweets` table. I want to see the column types. Thanks.